# Null-coalescing operator and order of operations?

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

Can anyone explain to me why this code:

```
int? a = 54;
decimal b = a ?? 0 / 100m;
```

`b` has the value of 54 ?

But if I add some brackets:

```
int? a = 54;
decimal b = (a ?? 0) / 100m;
```

It has the value of `0.54`?

I don't understand why this is the case. Because `a` has the value of 54 I would have thought the `??` operator would do nothing.

Comment: An operator can't "do nothing". It has to evaluate to _something_. What did you expect `b` to be in both cases?

Comment: `a ?? 0 / 100m` is `a ?? (0 / 100m)`. `(a ?? 0) / 100m` is of course something quite different.

Comment: Just as an aside (as there are quite a few responses that already answered your question), but doing `decimal b = a.Value / 100m;` will achieve what you are trying to do with less reliance on null coalescing operators, if you find it confusing.

Comment: You've overlooked very basic C# feature: parentheses have [highest priority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence) in order of evaluation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From MSDN:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

> The null-coalescing operator ?? returns the value of its left-hand
> operand if it isn't null; otherwise, it evaluates the right-hand
> operand and returns its result. The ?? operator doesn't evaluate its
> right-hand operand if the left-hand operand evaluates to non-null.

In your first case,

```
int? a = 54;  //Here "a" is not null
decimal b = a ?? 0 / 100m; //As "a" is not null, Value of "a" will be assigned to "b".
```

In your second case ,

```
  // precedence of "(<expression>)" is greater than "null coalescing operator" 
  int b = (a ?? 0) / 100m;
          //+++++++        --This will evaulate first and returns 54
         //          +++  -- This will be calculated as 54 / 100m i.e 0.54
```

Comment: "The ?? operator doesn't evaluate its right-hand operand if the left-hand operand evaluates to non-null" - ahh, without the brackets the 0/100m is treated like the right hand operator. Gotcha, thanks heaps!

Comment: That bit of documentation doesn't necessarily help you, because you don't know what the right-hand is. You need operator precedence to tell you that

Comment: @Charlieface, I agree with you regarding the precedence of an operator, but documentation is required to understand `null coalescing` operator and if OP understands it then he will understand why `b` is coming as `54` in his first case

Comment: @Charlieface The answer to the OP's first question `b has the value of 54 ?` is given in the documentation which I quoted in my answer

Answer (score 1):

`??` [has lower](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/) priority than `/`.

1 case:

`54 ?? (0 / 100) == 54`

2 case:

`(54 ?? 0) / 100 == 0.54`

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought:

```
decimal b = a ?? 0 / 100m;
```

is equivalent to:

```
decimal b = a ?? (0 / 100m);
```

So the `100` is not applied in the first case

Answer (score 1):

```
decimal b = a ?? 0 / 100m;
```

evaluates to

```
decimal b;
if (a == null)
{
    b = 0 / 100m;
}
else
{
    b = a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is purely a matter of operator precedence.**

[The documentation lists the order of precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence) for different operators, and you will see that `/` has a higher precedence than `??`, which means it will be evaluated first.

So,

```cs
decimal b = a ?? 0 / 100m;
```

is always evaluated as

```cs
decimal b = a ?? (0 / 100m);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int? a = 54;
decimal b = (a ?? 0) / 100m;
```

Evaluates as `b = (54) / 100m`, or `b = 0.54`, as you are seeing.